# Workaround to add shipment/tracking information to order and ignore the inventory check?

Tags: magento2.3, multi-source-inventory, submit-shipment

Our ERP is source of truth and inventory is being managed via API. The issue is that if a source under a stock is 0 and an order requires a shipment from that source, then we can't create a shipment. Is there a way to create a shipment with tracking information and ignore any inventory checks? Or just a way to force shipment creation in general?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a plugin, which when shipment creation command executes, checks the following

1. The qty of products available for products to be shipped
2. If it is less than require amount to be shipped or zero, add the required quantity to the product, which is in the order.

This way you will solve the problem.

Comment: Hey Nadeem. Thanks for the advice. Would you happen to know which module contains the logic for shipment creation? Or just in general where to find the modules on the server?